# What structure must be mysql indexed for my inner join sql statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I have nearly 1 million records for my firma table and this statement

```
SELECT    firma.adi,firma.tel, firma.cep, firma.adres,
          firma.etiket, sehir.ad, ilce.ilce_adi, ustkat.ust_adi 
FROM      firma 
inner     join sektor on sektor.s_fid=firma.id 
inner     join ustkat on ustkat.ust_id=sektor.s_ustid 
inner     join sehir on sehir.id=firma.sehir 
inner     join ilce on ilce.ilceid=firma.ilce 
WHERE     firma.uyeliktur<4 and firma.onay=1 and
          firma.zoom>0 and firma.koordinat>0 
GROUP BY  firma.id 
ORDER BY  firma.uyeliktur desc, firma.bastarih desc
```

how can i use mysql index for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want an index with all the columns in the `where` clause.  The first should be `onay` (because of the equality condition).  The second should be whichever condition is most restrictive.  One of these:

```
firma(onay, uyeliktur, zoom, koordinat)
firma(onay, zoom, uyeliktur, koordinat)
firma(onay, koordinat, uyeliktur, zoom)
```

Only the first two columns are used directly for looking up the rows for the `where`.  The other two are a slight efficiency so the `where` values are there.

If, by the way, these are actually flags, you are better off saying `zoom = 1` than `zoom > 0`.

Comment: Thanks, How can i use it in sql statment after indexing.

Comment: @Bagova . . . The SQL engine chooses the appropriate index automatically.  You can give it a hint, if you want, but that shouldn't be necessary.